# I am getting a class not found error when I try to connect R with AWS Redshift

Tags: r, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect R with redshift using the JDBC template they provide on their website.

I got the most updated version of the redshift jdbc and pulled JDBC() and it's not working.

```
install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)
library(RJDBC)

download.file('https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar','RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar')

driver_redshift <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver",
                        "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
```

I am getting an error that says Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the driver with binary mode:

```
download.file('https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar','RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar', mode="wb");
```

Then make sure that you're referring the correct jar:

```
driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
```